# MS EXCEL - Search and Extract all text before last instance of a Keyword in String

Tags: excel, excel-formula, instance, wildcard, text-extraction

With the use a MS Excel Formula - I need a formula that will extract all words Left or Before the last (Nth) instance of a specific keyword (non-case sensitive and partial wildcard matches) within a string of text.

SAMPLE TEXT STRING [Cell `A2`]:`Johnny is looking for a full-time job, because the job he once had went out of business, and although he is currently working full time he is not happy, and is aggressively seeking a more permanent full-time job that offers benefits and 1st Shift.`

1. Keyword Search [Cell `B2`]: `Full*time`
2. No. of Keywords found within text using `"Full*time" = 3`
3. Extract all Text Left/Before last instance/occurrence of Keyword -
   Results [Cell `C2`]:`Johnny is looking for a full-time job, because the job he once had went out of business, and although he is currently working full time he is not happy, and is aggressively seeking a more permanent full-time`

**Note:** The following `SUBSTITUTE` formula works but does not allow the use of a `SEARCH` formula to search and match keywords that are non-case sensitive and contains the use of wildcards.

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"^",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,""))))-1)
```

This formula works perfectly, but I'm only able to use it to extract `RIGHT`/AFTER the last instance of a wildcard keyword and would like something similar if possible.

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1-MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(B2,A2,ROW($1:$999)),0))+1)
```

Comment: May be the following works for you, with `TEXTAFTER` you cannot use wildcards, but it is easy to find the last occurrence. The following builds all possible combination of the wildcard to get the expected result: `=LET(txt,B1, lk,TEXTSPLIT(A2,"*"),del, TAKE(lk,,1)&{"-";" "}&TAKE(lk,,-1), after, TEXTAFTER(txt, del,-1,1), SUBSTITUTE(txt, after, ""))` let me know if that works so I can post it as an answer. In cell `A2` is the text to search: `"Full*time"` in `B1`. If you don't have too many possibilities for the wildcard, it could be a possible workaround.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for you provided reply to my requested solution; unfortunately when attempting to copy, paste and edit your formula within the respective referencing cells, I'm not able to get any results.  Are you able to provide the actual cell referencing as provided to include the use of the following cell fields (A2 = Text String and B2 = Full-time) versus "txt", B1, lk, del, as these formulas are not recognized in US version of Microsoft Office 365, as I'm aware of.. Thanks

Comment: ok, try this: `=LET(lk,TEXTSPLIT(B2,"*"),del, TAKE(lk,,1)&{"-";" "}&TAKE(lk,,-1), after, TEXTAFTER(A2, del,-1,1), SUBSTITUTE(A2, after, ""))`. `lk` splits the search string by the wilcard and `del` has all possibilities of delimiters. You can add more option of possible wild card replacement expanding the following array: `{"-";" "}`

Comment: David, thank you so very much, your provided solution to search and extract all text before the last instance or occurrence of the keyword works like magic.  Thanks Again for your assistance and sharing your talent.  I do ask,, although not necessary, but would be great, if it is possible using your provided Excel formula to adjust the occurrence by Nth.  In short, if I wanted to find and extract text before/left of the 2nd or 3rd instance of word within a string.

Comment: Lastly, when using the formula, it appears that it may have limitations to extracting text based on the total number of characters within a string.  I have some text string that contains more than 8000 (i.e., characters, spaces, punctuations, etc.) and returns "N/A" value.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Please check my answer and consider upvoting and/or accepting the solution. About your last comment, please share your Excel file in edit mode, so I can take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the wildcard is intended to consider different concatenation options, `TEXTAFTER` is a good candidate function to extract the text after a number of nth occurrence of a given substring. The problem is that `TEXTAFTER/TEXTBEFORE` functions do not accept wildcard values. In order to do that you would need to resolve all such concatenation options with specific values.

If the text to find with wildcard is on cell `B2` within the text `A2`. Put the following formula in `C2` to extract the text up to the last instance of of the lookup value:

```
=LET(txt,A2, n,3, lk,TEXTSPLIT(B2,"*"), del,TAKE(lk,,1)&{"-";" "}&TAKE(lk,,-1), 
 after,TEXTAFTER(txt,del,n,1), SUBSTITUTE(txt,after, ""))
```

**Notes**:

1. If you want to extract just up to the last occurrence of the lookup value, then set `n` value to `-1`.
2. The solution assumes there is always a wildcard (`*`) in the text to find. The solution can be extended to a more general case, when the exact text is provided (no `*`). For example checking the number of columns of `lk`. The case of no wildcards returns just a single column.

[image: output]

What it does is to split the lookup value by the wildcard via `TEXTSPLIT`, then build all possible delimiters to be used in `TEXTAFTER` via concatenation, considering a list of delimiters for each two words: `{"-";" "}`. For this example the values of `del` will be:

```
Full-time
Full time
```

Now we use `TEXTAFTER` to find the n-th occurrence (`n`) of any of the delimiters (`del`) and doing a case-insensitive search (`1`, last input argument). Once we have the text after the last delimiter (`after`), we use `SUBSTITUTION` to get the text before.

### Extract up to n-th occurrence of a given substring via SEARCH

You can use `REDUCE` function to iterate until `n`-th occurrence:

```
=LET(txt,A2, lk,B2, n,3, snd,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(lk,"*"),,-1),
 last,REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(n),LAMBDA(ac,_,SEARCH(lk, txt,ac+1))),
 endTkn,SEARCH(snd,txt,last+1)+LEN(snd)-1,
 LEFT(txt,endTkn))
```

The **problem** with this approach is that you need to avoid false positives, this is due to how `SEARCH/FIND` function work. If you have in the input text `full-times` instead of `full-time`, it will find this substring too, so you would need to build the look up value in a way it prevents it. For example to add space, comma, semi-colon, etc. to prevent all possible word delimiters, which makes the the formula more complex.

`SEARCH` function only returns the first position of the lookup value, therefore we use the name `snd` to find the end of the lookup value once the last occurrence was found.

### Extract up to last occurrence of a given substring via SEARCH

This is another way of doing it. You can create in the Name Manager the following recursive function `SEARCHLAST`:

```
=LAMBDA(lk,txt,[init],[last], LET(
 i,IF(ISOMITTED(init), 1, init),
 prev, IF(ISOMITTED(last), 0, last),
 current, SEARCH(lk, txt, i),
 IF(ISERR(current), prev, SEARCHLAST(lk, txt, current+1,current))))
```

What is does is basically a recursive call of `SEARCHLAST` until the value is not found, then take the value of previous iteration (`prev`). It uses `ISOMITTED` function to consider some input arguments (delimited by brackets `[]`) as optional, to have a more user friendly interface.

and now use it as follows:

```
=LET(txt,A2, lk,B2, last,SEARCHLAST(lk,txt), snd,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(lk, "*"),,-1),
 endTkn, SEARCH(snd, txt,last+1)+LEN(snd)-1,
 LEFT(txt, endTkn))
```

Comment: Re "*SEARCH function only returns the first position of the lookup value*", have you forgotten about that function's third parameter? Why not use simply `=UNIQUE(SEARCH(B2,A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2))))` which can then be indexed to find the nth occurrence?

Comment: Nice @JosWoolley, that would return the starting position of the lookup value for each occurrence, so no need to use `REDUCE` probably (but less efficient I would say, you have more iterations under this approach for a large input, correct?), but I think you still need to get to the end of the occurrence you are looking for. Because it uses a wildcard, I cannot use `LEN`, to get to the end, but maybe I am missing something.